# Endothermic peak in DSC

Tags: crystal-structure, differential-scanning-calorimetry

I have an endothermic peak, with no mass loss and no change in (organic) crystal structure (monitored by vt-pxrd). What can cause such effect? Also, excluding the options of impurities or instrumental errors.

Comment: See this document: Interpreting Unexpected Events and Transitions in DSC Results, https://www.tainstruments.com/pdf/literature/TA039.pdf

Comment: Without knowing any experimental detail, it will be a futile exercise to speculate anything.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the material in question?  (Maybe your PI doesn't offer clearance prior to filing a patent/submitting the work to a journal.)  Yet in analogy to zeolithes (e.g., ZSM-5), there are *metal* organic frameworks stable enough and with sufficient porosity for reversible absorption/desorption of molecules (e.g., water).  Once «entrapped» in the cavities, it becomes difficult to monitor these molecules of water because of its light atoms of smallish diffracting power (though this depends a bit on the X-ray source's brilliance and wavelength engaged).

Comment: @Buttonwood, OP says that there is no corresponding mass loss in that DSC event. It means nothing is leaving or entering the crystal system.

Comment: @AChem There may be multiple sites (both interior, as well as exterior) on (porous) materials, each with its own adsorption/desorption mode and energy for the molecules adsorbed.  Then, the system may identify just an other energetic minimum of adsorption when the adsorbed molecule(s) shuttle around; all without the adsorbed molecule leaving substrate for good (especially with more shallow energetic minima compared to ZSM-5, lighter molecules to adsorb/interaction with organic molecules).